# iOS - Canvas Scrollable in all Directions

Tags: ios, swift

I want to dynamically create content on the screen (think rectangles with labels), but due to the amount of content not all objects will be visible at once.

I want the objects to be placed on a canvas-like view which the user can scroll in all directions until they hit the edge (i.e., no more content exists beyond that point).

I was looking into `UIScrollView` but my understanding is that it allows scrolling only in one direction (vertical).

What components would be best suited to meet this requirement?

Comment: UIScrollView *can* scroll on both axis. You just need to make sure that its content view is large enough to do that.